# Can we access and write changes to Assets which are inside Android Plugin from Unity code?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, unity-game-engine, plugins

I analyzed my unity apk wherein I have used my own android plugin which contains some assets.

[image]

My main question is that can I change the values inside the contents.json file at runtime ?
If it is possible then how can I do it ?
Thank you !

Comment: No. Files in assets are read only at runtime.

Comment: @blackapps What other alternative can i perform ? I was thinking of putting my json in persistent storage (in internal storage) which can be accessed and read-write functions can be performed on it, efficiently. I have not done it before. Im wondering can i do it with the android plugin and unity connection ?

Comment: I suppose so. You have a quite legal wish.